# Using 2 keywords to pull correct id from json text?

Tags: python, json

Confused as to how to format this code correctly to specify the right color and size. My objective is to get the `id` of the color `Black` and size `Medium`. The output I'm trying to pull is `46779`. How would i set the code up to obtain the output I'm looking to pull?

Code -

```
color = "Black"
size_choice = 'Medium'

data1 = response1.text
size_data = json.loads(data1)['styles']
for entry in (size_data):
    if entry['name'] == color['sizes']:
        if entry['name'] == size_choice:
            size_id = (entry['id'])
            print("size id: ", size_id)
```

Currently the code outputs this error:

```
    if entry['name'] == color['sizes']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Json -

```
{"styles":[{"id":17289,"name":"Black","currency":"USD","description":null,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137366/sm/Am0dyTgmEJg.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137366/rs/Am0dyTgmEJg.jpg","swatch_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137366/ca/Am0dyTgmEJg.jpg","swatch_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137366/rc/Am0dyTgmEJg.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137366/mo/Am0dyTgmEJg.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137366/rm/Am0dyTgmEJg.jpg","bigger_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137366/zo/Am0dyTgmEJg.jpg","sizes":[{"name":"Small","id":46778,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Medium","id":46779,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Large","id":46780,"stock_level":0},{"name":"XLarge","id":46781,"stock_level":0}],"additional":[]},{"id":17290,"name":"White","currency":"USD","description":null,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137372/sm/tjvfNXfNMtY.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137372/rs/tjvfNXfNMtY.jpg","swatch_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137372/ca/tjvfNXfNMtY.jpg","swatch_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137372/rc/tjvfNXfNMtY.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137372/mo/tjvfNXfNMtY.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137372/rm/tjvfNXfNMtY.jpg","bigger_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137372/zo/tjvfNXfNMtY.jpg","sizes":[{"name":"Small","id":46782,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Medium","id":46783,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Large","id":46784,"stock_level":0},{"name":"XLarge","id":46785,"stock_level":0}],"additional":[]},{"id":17292,"name":"Lime","currency":"USD","description":null,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137369/sm/9JM2v7Uwwi4.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137369/rs/9JM2v7Uwwi4.jpg","swatch_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137369/ca/9JM2v7Uwwi4.jpg","swatch_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137369/rc/9JM2v7Uwwi4.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137369/mo/9JM2v7Uwwi4.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137369/rm/9JM2v7Uwwi4.jpg","bigger_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137369/zo/9JM2v7Uwwi4.jpg","sizes":[{"name":"Small","id":46790,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Medium","id":46791,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Large","id":46792,"stock_level":0},{"name":"XLarge","id":46793,"stock_level":0}],"additional":[]},{"id":17377,"name":"Heather Grey","currency":"USD","description":null,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137368/sm/eu2N2hb3yHY.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137368/rs/eu2N2hb3yHY.jpg","swatch_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137368/ca/eu2N2hb3yHY.jpg","swatch_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137368/rc/eu2N2hb3yHY.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137368/mo/eu2N2hb3yHY.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137368/rm/eu2N2hb3yHY.jpg","bigger_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137368/zo/eu2N2hb3yHY.jpg","sizes":[{"name":"Small","id":47110,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Medium","id":47111,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Large","id":47112,"stock_level":0},{"name":"XLarge","id":47113,"stock_level":0}],"additional":[]},{"id":17293,"name":"Brown","currency":"USD","description":null,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137367/sm/owzelzda9e0.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137367/rs/owzelzda9e0.jpg","swatch_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137367/ca/owzelzda9e0.jpg","swatch_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137367/rc/owzelzda9e0.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137367/mo/owzelzda9e0.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137367/rm/owzelzda9e0.jpg","bigger_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137367/zo/owzelzda9e0.jpg","sizes":[{"name":"Small","id":46794,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Medium","id":46795,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Large","id":46796,"stock_level":0},{"name":"XLarge","id":46797,"stock_level":0}],"additional":[]},{"id":17294,"name":"Pale Blue","currency":"USD","description":null,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/138342/sm/Wdv-CY_QC7Y.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/138342/rs/Wdv-CY_QC7Y.jpg","swatch_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/138342/ca/Wdv-CY_QC7Y.jpg","swatch_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/138342/rc/Wdv-CY_QC7Y.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/138342/mo/Wdv-CY_QC7Y.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/138342/rm/Wdv-CY_QC7Y.jpg","bigger_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/138342/zo/Wdv-CY_QC7Y.jpg","sizes":[{"name":"Small","id":46798,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Medium","id":46799,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Large","id":46800,"stock_level":0},{"name":"XLarge","id":46801,"stock_level":0}],"additional":[]},{"id":17295,"name":"Red","currency":"USD","description":null,"image_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137371/sm/-cCSOap0j1M.jpg","image_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137371/rs/-cCSOap0j1M.jpg","swatch_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137371/ca/-cCSOap0j1M.jpg","swatch_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137371/rc/-cCSOap0j1M.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137371/mo/-cCSOap0j1M.jpg","mobile_zoomed_url_hi":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137371/rm/-cCSOap0j1M.jpg","bigger_zoomed_url":"//d17ol771963kd3.cloudfront.net/137371/zo/-cCSOap0j1M.jpg","sizes":[{"name":"Small","id":46802,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Medium","id":46803,"stock_level":0},{"name":"Large","id":46804,"stock_level":0},{"name":"XLarge","id":46805,"stock_level":0}],"additional":[]}],"description":"All cotton classic Supreme t-shirt with printed graphic on front. \u003cspan class=\"red\"\u003e*T-shirts fit larger than previous styles. Please check sizing for updated measurements.\u003c/span\u003e","can_add_styles":false,"can_buy_multiple":false,"ino":"FW17T15","cod_blocked":false,"canada_blocked":false,"purchasable_qty":1,"new_item":false,"apparel":true,"handling":0,"no_free_shipping":false,"can_buy_multiple_with_limit":0}
```

Comment: Your json is malformed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `color['sizes']`: you have declared `color = "Black"`, so you cannot lookup the key `sizes` like this.

You need to add another level in your loop to search through the sizes :

```
for entry in (size_data):
    if entry['name'] == color:
        for size in entry['sizes']:
            if size['name'] == size_choice:
                size_id = (size['id'])
                print("size id: ", size_id)

>>> size id:  46779
```

Comment: Thank you very much